# Is there a gcc command to link all the .o files in the same directory and generate a .exe file?

Tags: c++, c, vim

For example,
 I have `file1.o`,`file2.o`,`file3.o` in the same directory.

Instead of type in `:!gcc -o final file1.o file2.o file3.o` in vim, is there a convenient way to key in that 3`.o` files? 
Maybe some searching and selecting commands? I don't know.

Can someone help me with that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can select all the files in a directory with a certain extension by using `*`:

```
gcc -o final *.o
```

If the files are numbered, you can also do:

```
gcc -o final file{1..3}.o
```

Which will run

```
gcc -o final file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

Comment: Woow, that's great `file{1..3}`, where have you find those tricks in the documentation?

Comment: My friend had a book called “A practical guide to Linux: Commands, Editors, and Shell Programming” and he lent it to me. I didn’t read the entire thing but I got a lot of useful stuff from skimming it!

Comment: @KeineLust It is in `man bash`, under "Brace Expansion" header. That manpage is a beast but it is superuseful to read.